# How is db passed value in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code 1 is a sample project from webpage , I don't know how the var db in `override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase)` in Code 1 is passed value.

I checked source code both ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper and SQLiteOpenHelper, and I don't understand yet!

**Code 1**

```
class ForecastDbHelper(ctx: Context = App.instance) : ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper(ctx,
        ForecastDbHelper.DB_NAME, null, ForecastDbHelper.DB_VERSION) {

    companion object {
        val DB_NAME = "forecast.db"
        val DB_VERSION = 1
        val instance by lazy { ForecastDbHelper() }
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.createTable(CityForecastTable.NAME, true,
                CityForecastTable.ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY,
                CityForecastTable.CITY to TEXT,
                CityForecastTable.COUNTRY to TEXT)

        db.createTable(DayForecastTable.NAME, true,
                DayForecastTable.ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY + AUTOINCREMENT,
                DayForecastTable.DATE to INTEGER,
                DayForecastTable.DESCRIPTION to TEXT,
                DayForecastTable.HIGH to INTEGER,
                DayForecastTable.LOW to INTEGER,
                DayForecastTable.ICON_URL to TEXT,
                DayForecastTable.CITY_ID to INTEGER)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db.dropTable(CityForecastTable.NAME, true)
        db.dropTable(DayForecastTable.NAME, true)
        onCreate(db)
    }
}
```

**ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper**

```
abstract class ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper(
    ctx: Context,
    name: String,
    factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory? = null,
    version: Int = 1
): SQLiteOpenHelper(ctx, name, factory, version) {

    private val counter = AtomicInteger()
    private var db: SQLiteDatabase? = null

    fun <T> use(f: SQLiteDatabase.() -> T): T {
        try {
            return openDatabase().f()
        } finally {
            closeDatabase()
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun openDatabase(): SQLiteDatabase {
        if (counter.incrementAndGet() == 1) {
            db = writableDatabase
        }
        return db!!
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun closeDatabase() {
        if (counter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
            db?.close()
        }
    }
}
```

**SQLiteOpenHelper**

```
public abstract class SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public String getDatabaseName() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public abstract void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase var1);

    public abstract void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase var1, int var2, int var3);

    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLHelper class is meant to make accessing your SQLite database simpler. passing the values to the super allows it to store the values for creating or upgrading the database.

The first time you call getWriteable database it will validate the version of DB against the one supplied in your constructor and if it is non-existent onCreate will be called, If it is newer onUpgrade will be called, otherwise normal operations will occur.

Also you posted false source above on the SQLiteOpenHelper it is actually this:

```
 public SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version,
        DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    if (version < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Version must be >= 1, was " + version);

    mContext = context;
    mName = name;
    mFactory = factory;
    mNewVersion = version;
    mErrorHandler = errorHandler;
}
```

So I'm not sure where you got your source code of the SQLiteOpenHelper but it is coded and much larger then your pasted abstract class above.